# Some users not seeing all TFS options in Visual Studio

Tags: team-foundation-server, visual-studio

I have two users who only see the following options in the Team Explorer tab in Visual Studio:
Changes, Branches, Sync and Settings

Another user, correctly sees all of them: 
Changes, Branches, Pull Requests, Sync, Work Items, Builds, Reports, Settings

[image]

The users who cannot see all the options appear to be members of the same relevant groups as the user who can.  The only difference I can see is the user who CAN see all the options is on Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.  The ones who can't are on Update 2.  Possibly a red herring?  I don't want to have the one who can see the options update, for fear he will lose the ability to access these options.

I am an admin, and on Visual Studio Update 2, and I see all the options.

TFS server 2015 Version 14.95.25122.0

From the web interface, all users are able to access pull requests and work items and see the builds.  So it doesn't seem to be a permission problem?  Possibly something they need to set in Visual Studio?  How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

We figured it out.  Maybe a bit obvious, but confused us for a while.

One use who didn't see the other options did not have the Team Project checked in Team Explorer.

Team Explorer->Manage Connections->Manage Connections->Connect to Team Project.

Strange that they could see Changes, Branches, Sync and Settings.  Probably because the project uses git and that is information Visual Studio could get from the Git folder, it didn't need to get it from the TFS server.

The second user who didn't see the other options DID have the project checked in Team Explorer.  Unchecking it and then checking it again fixed it.